# Perform and write functions on data using `by` in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am using data.table in R and trying to create and perform some functions that will do some calculations per group (`DT[i, j, by = ....]`) but I need to perform functions on the whole dataset within the function. As an example, taking the iris data, I can do the following to get the difference between group and overall means ("deviations"):

```
library(data.table)
dtIris <- data.table(iris)

# Sample means by group
dtIris[, mean(Petal.Length), by = "Species"]

# Overall sample mean
dtIris[, mean(Petal.Length)]

# Group deviations 
dtIris[, mean(Petal.Length), by = "Species"][, V1] - dtIris[, mean(Petal.Length)]
```

Alternatively I can make this a little more elegant with an `aggregate()` to get it into one expression:

```
# Within a single expression 
dtIris[, aggregate(Petal.Length ~ Species, FUN = mean)[,2] - mean(Petal.Length)]
```

And popping that into a function

```
# Create function
dtDeviations <- function(x, by){
  aggregate(x ~ by, FUN = mean)[,2] - mean(x)
}
dtIris[, dtDeviations(Petal.Length, Species)]
```

My question is, is there a way to make this fit the "data.table-way" such that I could **have my function interact with the `by` argument in the data.table notation and get means before and after grouping?** This would mean I could do the above by executing:

```
dtIris[, dtDeviations(Petal.Length), by = "Species"]
```

One possible solution would be to have the group means repeated by the length of each group, with a mean of that vector being the overall mean. It seems reasonable that there would be a way to access and act upon the grouped values within the function. This would be akin to

```
# Reconstructed overall mean
dtIris[, rep(mean(Petal.Length), .N), by = "Species"][, mean(V1)]
```

Comment: when you use `by`, `j` will only see each subset of `dtIris` corresponding to that `by`. You will need to refer to `dtIris` to see whole Petal.Length vector

Comment: yes, but in principle it could also see the three group means and counts for each group, allowing the overall mean to be reconstructed, for example: `x1 <- rnorm(112, 0, 1); x2 <- rnorm(481, 1, 1); mean(c(x1,x2)); mean(c(rep(mean(x1), length(x1)), rep(mean(x2), length(x2))))`

Comment: when calculating the mean for the first group, the means for the other 2 groups are not calculated yet. what is your use case for such a construct? there are quite a few good suggestions below to calculate at the global level before going down to the grouped level

Comment: The examples in my question also show that I can do this at the global level first, but I want to know if it possible to (and how to) do it inline with the standard `dt[i,j,by]` syntax... which is what the question says

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you'll find this more elegant but it's another option:

```
dtIris[, .(sum(Petal.Length), .N), by = "Species"
       ][, V1/N - sum(V1) / sum(N)]
```

Comment: Thanks for you contribution - i think you are on the right lines with picking up the group counts and group means to then reconstruct the overall mean - but I'm trying to find a way to get the by information from my `dt[i,j,by]` call to my function and perform an action on a non grouped level

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option for getting one expression would be:

```
dtIris[, .SD[, mean(Petal.Length), by = Species]$V1 - mean(Petal.Length)]
```

Output:

```
[1] -2.296  0.502  1.794
```

As for the functional form, in its simplest version you could do:

```
dtDeviations <- function(dt, x, by){
  dt[, .SD[, mean(get(x)), by = get(by)]$V1 - mean(get(x))]
}

# Call it like below

dtDeviations(dtIris, 'Petal.Length', 'Species')
```

Comment: Thanks @arg0naut91 but I'm trying to get a way to make the function (and similar functions) work within the data.table style so need to find out how to utilise the by information from `dt[i,j,by]` within my function

Answer (score 1):

Or just

`dtIris[, mean(Petal.Length)-mean(dtIris$Petal.Length), by = "Species"]`

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm trying to get to a way (if it is possible) to make functions like the deviations function while only having to specify the variable once (and only the variable) in the function with the by argument of data.table providing the grouping information rather than just an alternative way to do what I have already got